# Can you convert the data of a screen into a downloadable pdf report in Flutter?

Tags: pdf, flutter, download, report

In an application I am working on, I designed a screen for reports. Can I download that in a pdf report format in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the package, that might help you to create a pdf file with any stuff you would like
https://pub.dev/packages/pdf